# How to transform the root of IK to a custom position

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, inverse-kinematics

I want to make a VR game with the virtual environment inside a gym. The player acts as a fitness instructor that teaches guys to do pull ups. The player can push the NPC up by moving the VR controller upwards in holding the grab button. In this mode, the speed of push-ups made by the student is determined by the speed of movement of the VR controller.

I use DAZ to make both characters and import them into Unity. I think the key technique is in combining IK with animation. But as I know, the root of IK is by default the pelvis of the human-rig, and the basic IK coding in Unity can only bring IK behaviors to four limbs when using animations. How to efficiently achieve the aforementioned IK effect? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Just add positional/rotational constraints to the hands, and add a rigidbody to the pelvis.